# Highlight current date on w3widgets responsive calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I am designing a site with a calender to display events and I found [w3widgets](http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/) to be useful, but I'm having a problem on highlighting the current date over the calender, as it only highlights dates with events.

```
 <script>
       //I added this script to get me current date
        var d = new Date();
        var curr_date = d.getDate();
        var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
        var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
        var today = curr_year+ "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date;


 $( document ).ready( function() {
 $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
 time: today, //passing var today here works
 events: {
  "2013-04-30": {"number": 5, "badgeClass": "badge-warning", "url":    "http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar"},
  "2013-04-26": {"number": 1, "badgeClass": "badge-warning", "url": "http://w3widgets.com"},
  today: {"class": "active special"}, //This is what highlights a date and passing today as var is not working except a date like "2014-07-05"
  "2013-05-03": {"number": 1, "badgeClass": "badge-error"}, 
  "2013-06-12": {}}
});
});
</script>
```

If I do an alert of today, it displays current date though without a leading "0" I then just tried to create a variable var today = "2014-07-05" and passed it to that class and it still didn't work.

Comment: show css `class active special`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faced with the same issue. If you're using standard class names try:

```
.responsive-calendar .day.today a {
    background: red;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```